# Dependencies in git

Tags: git

I'm managing my own personal small site via git, more as a learning experience than for any real advantages in doing so. My workflow is generally:

1. Make changes on my desktop
2. Test file:///path/to/folder in my
   browser, and add/commit/change as appropriate
3. When I'm happy, push
   to origin, which I've set to be an EC2 instance, where a post-commit
   hook updates the working tree

I want to use [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/) to display maths equations on my site, but the MathJax folder is 128Mb, while the rest of my project barely comprises 1Mb altogether. Moreover, MathJax/ contains many small files, and (since it entered my working tree) operations like git add and git status are running very slowly - I assume because git is having to check every one of the files individually for status.

I'm tempted to `git reset --hard` to the commit before adding MathJax/, exclude the MathJax folder from my git repo (.gitignore), and simply add it to my webserver manually, on the grounds that I won't be changing MathJax regularly, and adding it to the repo seems to add considerable overhead for otherwise speedy operations. Then again, this means that my repo is not a self-contained entity, which seems conceptually wrong - I know how frustrated I get when I download a tasty-looking new script or service, and then I have to hunt down fifteen dependencies before it will run.

Obviously, no-one else is going to be working on this particular repo, but I'd like to get into good habits nonetheless. What's the best practice in a situation like this? Should large dependencies be included in a repo? If not, what's the best way of referring to them - README.md?

Comment: This sounds like a textbook case for a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: You're absolutely right - thanks for bringing that functionality to my attention, I'd never heard of it before! If you'd be so kind as to submit it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the git book:

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use
>   another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third
>   party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in
>   multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios:
>   you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be
>   able to use one from within the other.

You need to use a git feature called submodules. It's a git repository inside another git repository. See the [Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) or the [man pages](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html) for details.

Other option is git subtree (not to be confused with subtree merging). It's available in git versions 1.7.11 and later. A nice blog post describing the use of subtree here: https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/05/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree/